# Enabling RTC clock output from Device Tree

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, device-tree

I have an embedded device with RTC chip, system is running on customized Linux kernel. RTC chip has clock output pin which is connected to a test pad. Everything is configured through device tree.

By default, Linux kernel disables (or does not enable) clocks, that are not used - which is good. Except for this RTC clock output, which I need to be enabled.

One solution is to patch the RTC driver to force clock output enabled (maybe by adding a new device tree option). But I really want to avoid patching the kernel, especially as the required functionality already exists, I just can't figure out the correct configuration.

What I seem to need is a "dummy" clock consumer - or something similar, that forces the clock to be enabled. Is there such possibility in Linux kernel, configurable through device tree?

Comment: *"... as the required functionality already exists"* -- Your problem as currently posed seems hypothetical.  If there really is already a device driver for this RTC that can enable this *"clock output"* via a DT property, then identify the specific driver, clock, and property (or even better, show the init code).  Otherwise expect to *"patch the kernel"*.

Comment: @sawdust There isn't DT property for this driver (rtc-pcf8563) currently to enable this clock output. By "required functionality already exists" I mean, that driver registers clock provider, but does not enable that clock, as there are no consumers. Question is, how can I force kernel to enable this clock?

Comment: You need to write the dummy driver that will get and enable the clock. This has been on my todo list for a while but I didn't get to that yet.

Comment: I met the same problem as Erki had, have you got it fixed? I did a kernel module to get and set pcf8563 clockout, but failed on calling of `clk_get()` in kernel module. I don't know how to setup the name to call `clk_get()` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/750792/how-to-set-rtc-clock-output-in-linux-system.